# How do you hide/show forms in Android?

Tags: java, android

I come from Windows .Net forms development.

This is a pretty basic/fundamental question.

I'm attempting to build an Android app that will have multiple screens/forms (like most do)

My question is how do you achieve this in Android?

For example, a listview loads with menu items.  When the user clicks a menu item, how is the new layout/form loaded?

Do you simply set visibility of your UI controls based on user actions? Or is there a built in mechanism to control the loading of "forms"?

I hope this makes sense. I have some java background and have actually done a small amount of Android development. (But have yet to do an UI type things)

Edit: A better way to phrase this might be: What is the Android equivalent of forms?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These forms are called Activities, and each activity binded with a layout/view.

You have to use intents,

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyOtherActivity.class);
startActivity(newActivity);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to what Hesham Saeed has said, use

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoutId);
```

inside MyOtherActivity.java. This will load layoutId.xml layout file.